# How figure out methods and properties of jQuery object returned by apex.region(region_static_id).widget() method?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using APEX 20.2.0.00.20. `apex.region(region_static_id).widget()` method should return a jQuery object according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/region.html#widget). I am trying to figure out how to know what the object's properties and methods are, especially when they are not mentioned in the documentation. I tried running `apex.region(calendar_region_static_id).widget()` to return the object and inspect what properties and methods it has but I got `S.fn.init [div#CAL_calendar.fc.ui-widget.fc-ltr, prevObject: S.fn.init(1)] 0: div#CAL_calendar.fc.ui-widget.fc-ltr length: 1 prevObject: S.fn.init [document] __proto__: Object(0)`
I did not get the object. I do not know what s.fn.init or the rest of the returned code is?!
I see code like `apex.region("calendar_static_id").widget().fullCalendar("getView")`, so I assumed I should have gotten the jQuery object which has the "fullCalendar" method and more when I ran `apex.region(calendar_region_static_id).widget()`, but I have not.
Is this not the right way to inspect a jQuery object's properties and methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APEX integrates the FullCalendar widget, but it doesn't duplicate its documentation. Have a look [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-api) for a list of the FullCalendar methods and options.

---

In general, most (interactive) APEX regions are implemented as jQuery UI widgets. That means you can use them like this:

```js
$('selector').widgetName('methodName'); //invokes said method
$('selector').widgetName('methodName', 'param1'); //invokes said method with a parameter
$('selector').widgetName('option', 'optionName'); //gets a specific option
$('selector').widgetName('option', 'optionName', 'newVal'); //sets a specific option
```

What's more, you can inspect all available options by running:

```js
$('selector').widgetName('option');
```

And even have a look at the internal object, see all methods, public and otherwise, via:

```js
$('selector').widgetName('instance');
```

---

Moreover, via its region interface, APEX offers an even easier way to reach those methods and options, even without having to know a region's widgetName:

```js
// this
$('widgetSelector', 'staticId').widgetName('methodName');
// is equivalent to
apex.region('staticId').widget().widgetName('methodName');
// is quivalent to
apex.region('staticId').call('methodName');
```

The last way is the shortest and doesn't require knowing the real widget's id or widget name.

---

All of this helps when dealing with regular APEX widgets, such as the Interactive Grid.

```js
apex.region('emp').call('instance'); //inspects all methods
apex.region('emp').call('option');   //inspects all options
```

This however does not work on the FullCalendar region, for reasons that are beyond me. It should help you navigate all other APEX regions, but for the FullCalendar you'll have to resort to their API docs.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the plenty of methods you mentioned to get what I need. But, I am still curious why my way does not work?! The method "widget()" should return a jquery object. Why does not it?!

Comment: It does return a jQuery object though.
A jQuery object is just an array of DOM elements, with extra functions sitting on top of that array, such as .append(), .remove() etc. By calling these methods they will affect every DOM element in said array.
Say you have a calendar region with staticId "cal".
apex.region('cal').widget() will return the same thing as:
$('#cal_calendar')
1/2

Comment: If you inspect this value, it's just an array like [div#cal_calendar.fc.ui-widget.fc-ltr]
Additionally, on this array you can call .append(), .remove() etc,
but also .fullCalendar()
Now what you can pass into .fullCalendar() is a whole different story.
2/2

Comment: 1- I thought that jQuery object is the same as a regular javaScript object. Now after surfing the web, I know that it's an array-like collection for the elements selected. 2- I assume that all jQuery objects have methods in common i.e ".length()" but each one could have a method that does not exist in the others, right? 3- your code "apex.region('staticId').widget().widgetName('methodName');", how did you know that the jQuery object returned by widget() has a method with the same name as the widget name i.e fullCalendar or interactiveGrid, etc...? Where do I get such information?

Comment: 2- I think if the fullCalendar code was included on the page, you can call .fullCalendar on *any* jQuery object. If that object has already been initialized via .fullCalendar({options}) previously, usually by APEX, you can then call methods and set/get options. If you try to call .fullCalendar() methods or get/set options on a jQuery element which has not been been initialized as a fullCalendar yet, you'll probably get some error along the lines of "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on ... prior to initialization", eg $('body').fullCalendar('option').Yet $('body').fullCalendar still exists.

Comment: Sorry @Stefan for bothering you. You're talking about calling methods. But I am asking how to know what methods I can call. I'll try to be clearer. How to discover what methods and properties a jQuery object has? for example, if we are talking about a javascript object var x = {color: blue, type: car, testMethod: function(){alert('hi')}}, I will be able to see what properties and methods it has by just running "x" in the console. Is there a similar way to do the same with jQuery objects?
I hope it got clearer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I need to know what methods and properties the jQuery object returned by widget() method has. I assume that it includes fullCalendar() and interactiveGrid().

Comment: Yes I was still going to respond with "3- ". Something else intervened. So 3- 
If you inspect *any* jQuery object in the console, say $('body'), and you expand that weird S.fn.init object, you should see the array of elements, a property length, maybe a property prevObject, but also \_\_proto\_\_.
If you expand \_\_proto\_\_, you should see all possible methods that you can call on that object. It's a big list though. On a page with a calendar, fullCalendar should be there. On a page with an IG, you should see grid and interactiveGrid.
Does this help?

Comment: That's what I have been missing. I tried with a page that has an IG and could not find "fullCalendar" method, only grid() and interactiveGrid(). Now I tried it with a page with a calendar and I found the fullCalendar(). 1- I can understand I can not call methods for a widget that hasn't been initialized yet, but Why are the methods only displayed in the --proto- node when the page has the widget i.e IG or Calendar? 2- How could I know the parameters the method accept?

Comment: 3- I can see in the documentation, the interactiveGrid is referred to as a "Widget" not a method, why is that?

Comment: 3- "interactiveGrid" is first and foremost a jQuery UI widget, because it implements the jQuery UI widget interface. For simplicity, "interactiveGrid" is *also* the name this widget uses to create instances and interact with these instances later.

Comment: 1- The whole __proto__ thing is a bit too complex for a stackoverflow comment. But I'm sure google has some nice explanations- it has to do with objects and inheritance in javascript.

Comment: 2- This I explained in my main answer. widgetName('option') to get all options. widgetName('options', 'xyz') to get a specific option, widgetName('options', 'xyz', 'newVal') to set a specific option. widgetName('method') to call a specific method. widgetName('instance') to inspect all methods/options- basically by looking inside the widget instance. Again, not sure why this doesn't work for the calendar.
But as as a rule of thumb... just consult the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is missing a lot, for example, there is nothing about the Calendar! <br>
- If I use apex.region('IG_static_Id').widget(); when I have an IG on the page, then look at the <strong>proto</strong> node, I find the interactiveGrid() function but I can not know that it accepts another method i.e getActions and getCurrentView. Hot to get that information? That's what I was referring to.

Comment: I would do the following: have an IG with ID emp and try: apex.region('emp').call('instance'), then look through the proto...
Also.. all of these methods are documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html
and here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/grid.html

For the calendar, check:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-api

Comment: Pardon me, I still can not find my way. 1- How should I know the parameters interactiveGrid() method accepts? Sometimes I see it taking one parameter i.e apex.region("IG").widget().interactiveGrid('getCurrentView'); and sometimes with two parameters i.e .....interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');. I think it has multiple signatures, right?
2- Correct me if I am wrong, jQuery UI widgets are combination of HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery code, right?

Comment: I suggest using apex.region(id).call(zyz) as opposed to apex.region(id).widget().interactiveGrid(xyz).

Have a look here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#getViews

getViews is a function that accepts an optional parameter. If you specifiy it, you will get back 1 view, if you don't, you'll get back an object of views.

so .call('getViews', 'grid') is the same as .call('getViews').grid

But this is specific to getViews.

In general:
widgetName('functionName', ...parameters)

Comment: I will choose to stick with apex.region("id).call(methodName) because it's the shortest and easiest one. But it seems that it only works with calling interactiveGrid widget's methods. I tried to call a method of the "grid" widget i.e "getActiveRecordId" and it threw "no such method 'getActiveRecordId' for interactiveGrid widget instance" error. How should I call the other widgets' methods i.e "grid", "iconList", "recordView", etc...?

Comment: by the way, I tried "$("#IG").interactiveGrid('getCurrentView');" as you stated in the first response and it always get me error "cannot call methods on interactiveGrid prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getCurrentView'".

Comment: The selector is incorrect then. "IG" might be the static ID of the region, through which you could get the widget, but the widget's ID is "IG_grid" (or something like that). Have a look through the DOM. But still, I suggest only going through apex.region.

Comment: To your earlier question: to get to the grid widget, you'd have to do something like: apex.region('emp').call('getCurrentView').view$.grid('gridWidgetMethodHere')

Comment: Just a side note: although it might all seem like a mess, it's actually quite elegantly implemented- once you understand it :')
I suppose another layer of abstraction could help here. Or at least more practical examples in the docs....

Comment: This code worked: "apex.region('emp').call('getCurrentView').view$.grid('gridWidgetMethodHere');" but when I tried to replace "grid" with "iconList" or "recordView" to get access to their methods i.e " apex.region('IG').call('getCurrentView').view$.recordView('refresh'); ", it threw error: "cannot call methods on recordView prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' ". I asked a question about this exact point.Kindly have a look at it when you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934347/is-there-a-standard-way-to-get-access-to-interactivegrid-widgets-and-subwidgets

Comment: The more important question to me is, where did you learn to deal with those api's with this lack of resources. The docs messes a lot of information and no articles talk about it. Just some code lines to copy and paste if you need them.