# Is there a standard way to get access to interactiveGrid widget's and subwidgets' methods?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle AEPX 20.2. At the top of the left panel here [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html), there are a number of widgets. I assume all of them are sub widgets to the `interactiveGrid` widget except for `treeview` widget, am I right? If right or wrong, is there a standard way that get me access to those widgets' methods?
I tried `apex.region("regionStaticId).call('methodName');` but it seems to give access only to interactiveGrid widget's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. `.call` will only give you access to the main widget- the `interactiveGrid` widget. With `.call` you can invoke things like refresh, focus, resize, etc. These are methods which you can invoke for **all** IG views. They are very generic. But most importantly, the `interactiveGrid` widget also contains the methods `getCurrentView` and `getViews`.

Via these 2, you will get an instance of the `interactiveGridView` interface. Most notabily, this instance will contain a reference to the underlying model, but also a jQuery object named `view$`, which points to the DOM elemenent implementing the more specific jQueryUI widgets like `grid` (used by the default table like view) or `tableModelView` (used by detail and icon view).

For 99% of cases, you'll really only have the grid view available, so this will suffice:

```js
apex.region('emp').call('getCurrentView').view$.grid(<<gridWidgetMethod>>);
```

If you have also enabled an icon view or a detail view, getCurrentView might not be enough, so we have to use `getViews`, and specify exactly what we want. So for the detail view, you might do something like this:

```js
apex.region('emp').call('getViews', 'detail').view$.tableModelView(<<tableModelViewWidgetMethod>>);
```

Note that for some of the `detailModelView` methods to work, your markup must follow some guidelines, like each record having a `data-id` attribute set. Have a look at the documentation for more info.

For the icon view is slightly different.

```js
apex.region('emp').call('getViews', 'icon').view$.tableModelView('getIconList').<<iconListMethod>>()
```

It's also a tableModelView widget, which internally creates an `iconView` widget. To get to this one, we must call `getIconList`. However, this will not return a jQuery object, but the actual widget (internal) instance. So methods are called directly, and not by passing them in as strings.

Keep in mind the `view$` property will only be available once you've clicked into that view. If you have a grid view and icon view, and the user has only been working in the grid view, the icon one will not be yet available. It must have first initialized.

The recordView is also slightly different. Because it only exists in context of the grid view, we can get a reference to it like this:

```js
apex.region('emp').call('getViews', 'grid').singleRowView$.recordView(<<recordViewWidgetMethod>>);
```

[This diagram](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/IG_arch.jpg) attempts to explain the IG architecture. It is somewhat out of date, for example the "groupByView" hasn't made it into APEX (yet at least), but it does the job.

---

An overview

```js
var region = apex.region('emp');
var gridView = region.call('getViews', 'grid').view$;       // must have been initialized
var detailView = region.call('getViews', 'detail').view$;   // must have been initialized
var iconDetailView = region.call('getViews', 'icon').view$; // must have been initialized
var iconViewWidget = iconDetailView.tableModelView('getIconList');

// calling the refresh method of the different views
gridView.grid('refresh');
detailView.tableModelView('refresh');
iconViewWidget.refresh();
```

---

In short, there doesn't appear to be a "standard way" of invoking these specific view methods. There is a different way to get to each view, and different aspects to consider when working with them.

---

Comment: "grid" and "recordView" worked fine, but "iconList" and "detail" did not. They threw error: "cannot call methods on "widget name" prior to initialization". I tried the iconList after clicking the icon view's button to initialize it, and did the same with the detail view.
Should not all views be initialized when page rendering is finished?

Comment: I guess not. The thinking was probably- why load something that might not be used?

The above works fine for me. If you create a testcase on apex.oracle.com I could take a look.

Comment: My mistake! I think tableModelView works because it returns a jQuery object when using "refresh" method as you will see in the example button. It's just the iconList that produces the error. I added other buttons for the rest of the widgets and I hope you can give me examples for using them. ws=ESLAM_WS un=forhelp pwd=Helppwd$ "H" is capital app=test page=IG @Stefan

Comment: Are you still there @Stefan ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay,
Indeed, my original response was incorrect.
It turns out there is no "standard" way of reaching the methods of the different views.

The grid one is clear.
The singleRowView one is accessed through the grid one.
The detail one is clear, but you have to use the correct markup.
The icon one is the trickiest, as you have to go through tableModelView, and then suddenly call the methods normally, and not in a jQueryUI way anymore.

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer and let me know if everything described makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

you mean something like this:

```
apex.region("my_ig").call("getActions").invoke("save");
```

here you will find blog series about IG

https://tm-apex.blogspot.com/

Comment: That's the same line of code I mentioned. You're accessing "getActions" which is a method of interactiveGrid widget, but you can not call("getColumns") for example which is a method of "iconList' widget.